# Convert little endian to big endian in c#

Tags: c#

I want to convert string "8BABEEF9D2472E65" to big endian.

I already input in this function, I receive UINT Size error.. How can i do?

Function :

```
    string bigToLittle(string data)
    {
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(data, 16); 
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
        string retval = "";
        foreach (byte b in bytes)
            retval += b.ToString("X2");
        return retval; 
    }
```

Comment: Is this mean to be a 64-bit integer? It's not clear why you'd want to return a string rather than parsing it as a `long` or `ulong` if so... (Converting it to `int` is definitely a bad approach, as you've got 64 bits of data, not 32...)

Comment: In order to successfully convert little endian to big endian (or vice versa), you need to know the size (in bytes) of each data type. For instance, are they bytes (then you're done), 16 bits integers (swap the two bytes), 32 bits integers (reverse order), 64 bits, etc. In other words, is that hex string supposed to be one number, or is it an array of numbers? This is critically important.

Comment: Please state your expected output for the given string,

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary` class.

```
string input = "8BABEEF9D2472E65";
var output = new SoapHexBinary(SoapHexBinary.Parse(input).Value.Reverse().ToArray())
            .ToString();
```

Output: 652E47D2F9EEAB8B

Or Maybe

```
var output = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(long.Parse(input, NumberStyles.HexNumber))
            .ToString("X");
```

Comment: you can accomplish same with less code :) long.Parse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)

Comment: @Taumantis  Have you really read my answer? I posted it ~55 mins ago before your comment :)

Comment: yes I did, i ment that `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(long.Parse(input, NumberStyles.HexNumber))
            .ToString("X");` can be written also as only `var output =long.Parse(input, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)`. Sorrry to point it out i just do not see reason for `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder`, but maybe you can 
support it with some theory, becouse ours questioner created such a full of specific information question :P I tried to read between lines but... maybe you come with something else? :)

Comment: @Taumantis Question is : `Convert little endian to big endian in c`. `HostToNetworkOrder` does this for the long parsed by `long.Parse`. need more explanation? Just read it again. I didn't write a wall of text to do the this simple thing...

Answer (score 3):

As we can not guess what exacly you want as output I let myself write missing possibilities(in code comments)... you can choose which you trully need:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static int ReverseBytes(long val)
    {
        byte[] intAsBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(val);
        Array.Reverse(intAsBytes);
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(intAsBytes, 0);
    }

    private static string IntToBinaryString(long v)
    {
        string s = Convert.ToString(v, 2);
        string t = s.PadLeft(32, '0');
        string res = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (i > 0 && i%8 == 0)
                res += " ";
            res += t[i];
        }
        return res;
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sValue = "8BABEEF9D2472E65";
        long sValueAsInt = long.Parse(sValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        //output {-8382343524677898651}
        string sValueAsStringAgain = IntToBinaryString(sValueAsInt);
        //output {10001011 10101011 11101110 11111001 11010010 01000111 00101110 01100101}
        byte[] data = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(sValue);
        string decodedX = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(data);
        string retval = data.Aggregate("", (current, b) => current + b.ToString("X2"));
        //output {0038004200410042004500450046003900440032003400370032004500360035}

        char[] decodedX2 = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(data).Reverse().ToArray();
        StringBuilder retval2 = new StringBuilder(); //output {56E2742D9FEEBAB8}
        foreach (var b in decodedX2)
            retval2.Append(b);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

and bout yours Method:

```
public static string bigToLittle(string data)
{
    long sValueAsInt = long.Parse(data, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(sValueAsInt);
    string retval = "";
    foreach (byte b in bytes)
        retval += b.ToString("X2");
    return retval; //output {652E47D2F9EEAB8B}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked @Sebatsian's answer but I ran into issues with the entry being padded by extra zeroes, so I modified it slightly, in case you are doing something like converting Linux VMUUID's in Azure over to standard format.  I made use of `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder`, which handles breaking your long into bytes and reversing them.

```
private string BigToLittle(string data)
{
    long sValueAsInt = long.Parse(data, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    var length = data.Length;
    return IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(sValueAsInt).ToString("X2").Substring(0, length);
}
```

In usage:

```
    string uuid = "090556DA-D4FA-764F-A9F1-63614EDA0163";
    
    private string BigToLittle(string data)
    {
        long sValueAsInt = long.Parse(data, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        var length = data.Length;
        return IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(sValueAsInt).ToString("X2").Substring(0, length);
    }
    var elements = uuid.Split(new char[] { '-' });
    var outMe = new List<string> { };
    foreach (var item in elements)
    {
        outMe.Add(BigToLittle(item));
    }
    var output = String.Join("-", outMe);
    //DA560509-FAD4-4F76-F1A9-6301DA4E6163
```